# Fetch distinct object from a collection using GroupBy on a single column in LINQ to Objects/SQL/Entity

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities

I have a Database table Country with example data as follows:

```
CountryId        CountryName         Year
1                 UK                 2001
2                 UK                 2003
3                 UK                 2004
4                 USA                2001
5                 USA                2005
```

I have a GetAllCountries() method on my DataAccessLevel:

```
public static IEnumerable<Country> GetAllCountries()
    {
        List<Country> countries;
        using (var context = new ReportEntities())
        {
            countries= (from c in context.Countries 
                       select c).ToList();
        }
           return countries;
    }
```

That should return a list of Country objects which I can then use to bind a DropdDownList to show data. When I bind I use the to pick specific attributes to display from the object. So where I need List so that later I can use it in different data loading methods. For example in LoadCountriesToDdlList():

```
{
       var countries= _transactionService.GetAllCountries();
        var distinctcountries = countries.GroupBy(c=> c.CountryName); 
        _UIDDListCountries.DataSource = distinctcountries ;
}
```

Expected result for the list: 
**CountryName**
      UK
      USA

I have tried lot of different ways to edit the query but failed every time. Any ideas?

Tried: GrouppBy, OrderedBy, Distinct(), selecting new object, but no luck. The problem seem that I am trying to return a list of Objects.

Comment: do you want to return two Country objects? How other fields in them should be populated? Or is it just two string values?

Comment: what are you trying to get back? A list with two elements UK and USA?

Comment: Have you tried [`Distinct`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb338049.aspx)?

Comment: Have you tried using distinct and just selecting c.CountryName?

Comment: I have tried using Distinct(),no luck. I am trying to get a list of Countries which will have distinct name. Since I have Same Country many times in the database. c.CountryName will be String, so didn't work.

Comment: @shaz what year should that country have?

Comment: what did you use Distinct ON? the records? Or the extracted list of names?

Comment: I used (from c in context.Countries 
                       select c).Distinct().ToList();

Comment: Does CountryID matter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want the dropdown to have Distinct country name from the above table you could try the below:

```
{
       var countries= _transactionService.GetAllCountries();
        var distinctcountries = countries.GroupBy(c=> c.CountryName); 
        _UIDDListCountries.DataSource = distinctcountries.Select(g => g.First());
}
```

The above code first groups all the countries objects based on CountryName and then we assign only the first object of each grouped result to the dropdown datasource.

If you want to customize your text field value you could create an anonymous type and use it. Code below:

```
{
       var countries= _transactionService.GetAllCountries();
       var distinctcountries = countries.GroupBy(c=> c.CountryName); 
       _UIDDListCountries.DataSource = distinctcountries.Select(g => new { CountryID = g.First().CountryID, CountryName = g.First().CountryName ,Text = String.Concat(g.First().CountryName, "--", g.First().Year) }) ;
       _UIDDListCountries.DataTextField = "Text";
       _UIDDListCountries.DataValueField = "CountryName";
}
```

NOTE: This works when you are only concerned about showing distinct values of CountryNames in the dropdown and not considering the CountryID and the Year in any case

Comment: I can't get over how bad this answer is. You've got some kind of database ID (used as a foreign key in who knows what). Doing this method is going to break at some point down the line, and you're going to have a very, very hard time to find out why.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want this

```
countries= (from c in context.Countries 
            select c.CountryName).Distinct()
```

Comment: `countries` and return type should probably then have `List<string>`, or even better `IEnumerable<string>`

Comment: can not do that since I am trying to return a list of Countries, not List of string.

Comment: then what you're doing makes no sense - you have multiple instances of the same country, and you want to chose one of them to return? Why? is this sensible? Or are you trying to extract specific information where the year isn't important?

Comment: I am trying to extract only the CountryName for a DDList where YEAR does not matter.Currently I get duplicate CountryNames. That's why I only need single instance.

Comment: What do you mean by a DDList? and what is a "Country" object? I'm assuming it's a row in the table above?

Comment: DropDownList, Country object hast (ID, Name, Year). Yes it is a row in the table. But same country is multiple time in the table with different YEAR.

Comment: It also has a different ID, which ID should it use? that's kind of important. It sounds like your DB Schema is a little up the creek and that you need to look at that.

Comment: Why the downvote? I answered the question as posed, and when the OP expanded a little bit I asked a further question to try to get to the core of the issue, which was ignored...

Answer (score 0):

`GroupBy()` should give you what you're after:

```
var grouped = context.Countries.GroupBy(c => c.CountryName);

    foreach (var country in grouped)
    {
        var distinctCountryName = country.Key;  //Access field used to group
        var firstMatchingCountry = country.First();
        var matchingCountriesInAList = country.ToList();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following if only country name matters...as in countryId and year don't.

```
//Note, you'll probably want to change this function name because it's
//not actually getting all countries anymore
public static IEnumerable<Country> GetAllCountries()
{
    using (var context = new ReportEntities())
    {
        //Note, this LINQ query can also return an IQueryable.  This is useful
        //if you're querying a database because you'll be doing more logic in SQL
        //and transferring less data from your database to memory on your C# machine
        IEnumerable<Country> countries = 
                 from c in context.Countries
                 group c by c.CountryName into countriesGroupedByName
                 select countriesGroupedByName.First();
        return countries;
    }
}
```

Do something like the following if you care about `countryId` and `countryName`.

```
IEnumerable<Country> countries = 
                    from c in context.Countries
                    group c by c.CountryName into countriesGroupedByName
                    select countriesGroupedByName.OrderBy(c => c.CountryId).First();
```

Comment: actually I need only CountryName, ID or YEAR does not matter at all.

Comment: So it sounds like you want a list of countries with distinct names.  My first suggestion should return that list.